# how to get weekly unbound retention from bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I Need to get the weekly retention users.
If user has made the transaction in week 4, that user is there in Week 0, week 1, week 2, week 3, week 4.

If User made transaction in week 0, and week 3 then user will be there in Week 0, week 1, week 2, week 3
Thanks @bbaird,

I am updating the question with precise information and question

Here is my table data

| TxnId | userid | transactedWeek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | U1 | 0 |
| T2 | U2 | 0 |
| T3 | U3 | 0 |
| T4 | U4 | 0 |
| T5 | U1 | 0 |
| T6 | U2 | 0 |
| T7 | U6 | 0 |
| T8 | U1 | 1 |
| T9 | U8 | 1 |
| T10 | U12 | 1 |
| T11 | U3 | 1 |
| T12 | U5 | 1 |
| T13 | U9 | 2 |
| T14 | U15 | 2 |
| T15 | U20 | 3 |
| T16 | U15 | 3 |
| T17 | U15 | 3 |
| T18 | U8 | 3 |
| T19 | U9 | 4 |
| T20 | U20 | 5 |

The Result I am looking for

| Week | active_users_count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |

Users count is kinda cumulative but unique users.

For example if user-1 has performed transaction 3 times in week-0, then count for week-0 is 1

If User-1 has performed 3 transactions in week-0, 2 transaction in week-2, 1 transaction in week-3,
then count will be like this

week-0 -> 1  (i.e. he has performed transaction >= week 0)

week-1 -> 1  (i.e. he has performed transaction >= week 1)

week-2 -> 1  (i.e. he has performed transaction >= week 2)

week-3 -> 1  (i.e. he has performed transaction >= week 3)

There can be any number of weeks. It is not fixed to 4 weeks or 8 weeks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to dba.SE.  Please post table definitions (relevant columns only) and sample data so others can better assist you.

Comment: Hi, the sample data is provided in the link that i have posted. 
As the data i have added is 1000s of rows, i provided as link.

Comment: Links are often blocked by employers (and may not be durable) so it's better to include the sample data AND table definitions in your question.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of blocking the links. I have updated with sample data in body. but as the limited num of chars, i have given some limited data.

Comment: You can just provide enough information so a reasonable person could deduce what you have and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @bbaird, I have updated the question according to your suggestion. I hope it is precise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118169/discussion-between-bbaird-and-mallikarjun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a relatively straightforward aggregation by `Week`, but you will need to join all records greater than or equal to the current week and take your distinct count from there.

However, that's going to be a lot of rows for Bigquery to work through, so this will probably work better for the platform:

```
SELECT
  TransactedWeek AS Week
 ,SUM(SUM(LastWeekInd))
    OVER
      (
        PARTITION BY 
          1 
        ORDER BY 
          TransactedWeek
        ROWS BETWEEN 
          CURRENT ROW
            AND
          UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
      ) AS active_users_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      UserId
     ,TransactedWeek
     ,CASE
        WHEN TransactedWeek = MAX(TransactedWeek) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS LastWeekInd
    FROM
      <Your Table>
  ) x
GROUP BY
  TransactedWeek
```

You can add logic to limit the ranges in the inner query.

Note: if you have any weeks missing from your data, they will be missing in your final result (although the counts will still be accurate).  If you have weeks with no transactions, you may need to generate a list of weeks and left join these results to that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding but the results is not correct. As your query groups and counts for that particular week. But check the sample data and result. count is not at that particular week but subsequent weeks as well

Comment: According to your query, week-0 have count of 5, but it actually has to be 11

Comment: @Mallikarjun fixed

Comment: Worked Like a charm. Thanks for saving the day. :)